# Issue with Regular expression for each statement

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am unable to understand where I am going wrong with the regular expression below. The regex is failing to match here.

```
    Dim TextLine as string="             1   -7.007184E+02   2.8E+01    0.0                               
    2   -2.450452E+04  -1.8E-01    0.0           "
    Dim regExResults As New Regex("(\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+E-?\d+)\s+(-? 
    \d+\.\d+E-?\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)")
    Dim ID as long
    Dim Data1 as double
    Dim Data2 as double
    Dim Data3 as double
    For Each match As Match In regExResults.Matches(TextLine)
        ID = match.Groups(1).Value
        Data1= match.Groups(2).Value
        Data2= match.Groups(3).Value
        Data3 = match.Groups(4).Value
    Next match



     'Dim regExResults As New Regex("\s+(\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+E-?\d+)\s+(-? 
     \d+\.\d+E-?\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)")  'Alternative Regex
```

I was expecting two matches as shown below and the loop repeats twice, unfortunately, its not even getting into the loop. Can some one suggest me the way forward. The TextLine is extracted from a text file.

<1   -7.007184E+02   2.8E+01    0.0>

<2   -2.450452E+04  -1.8E-01    0.0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your pattern. In this part you've forgotten to check for `E+##`:

```
(-?\d+\.\d+E-?\d+)
```

This will match for instance `-1.8E-01`, but not `-1.8E+01`. You need it to check for the plus as well, thus you should change it to:

```
(-?\d+\.\d+E[+-]?\d+)
```

New pattern:

```
(\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+E[+-]?\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+E[+-]?\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)
```

Also note that by adding spaces or line breaks in the string they will by default also be interpreted as part of the pattern, so you should disable that by specifying [`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions):

```
Dim regExResults As New Regex("(\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+E[+-]?\d+)\s+(-?
\d+\.\d+E[+-]?\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)",
RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```